# Map returns null when declared and using "containsKey"

Tags: apex, map

Below is my code. As i commented, I am getting false and null for the last 2 lines even though I do get and input the key.

```
final static String REQID = 'Req ID';
static Map <String, Integer> fieldNumberMap_questions = new Map <String, Integer> {'﻿Req ID'=>0}; 
system.debug(fieldNumberMap_questions);
system.debug(fieldNumberMap_questions.keyset());
system.debug(REQID);
system.debug(fieldNumberMap_questions.containsKey(REQID)); //getting false
system.debug(fieldNumberMap_questions.get('Req ID')); //getting null
```

Comment: you have a hidden char in your map definition before the `R`

Comment: Your `REQID` and `fieldNumberMap_questions` are both static, are you sure you're in a static context when running your debugs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After I copy pasted your code in Developer console
[image]

Notice the red dot. Its a empty space (a hidden character which might come due to copy paste in your code) and due to this you are not getting any result.

Once I clear this and test again it works fine for me.

[image]

Comment: man, one of these days I'll remember that hidden characters can cause all sorts of weird issues. Today was not that day. +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks Tushar for pointing out.. spent almost 1 hour trying to figure out what is going wrong though everything looked straightforward.